# detect change value of the textbox and re-bind the dropdownlist value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox which is coming from the popup value. This value of the textbox  will also rebind the selected value of my dropdownlist in the main page.

```
  @Html.TextBox("test", "", new { @style = "width:500px", @class = "sa-required" })
```

I have do like this

```
 $('#test').bind('input', function () {
        alert('Content has been changed');
        $("#mydropdownlist").val(data);
 });
```

and like this

```
$('#test').keyup(function () {
        if ($('#test').val() != content) {
            content = $('#test').val();
            alert('Content has been changed');
            $("#mydropdownlist").val(data);
}});
```

and like this

```
 $('#test').live('change', function () {
        alert('test');
        $("#mydropdownlist").val(data);
 });
```

and like this

```
$('#test').change(function () { $("#mydropdownlist").val(data); });
```

the problem is, my textbox is not firing when the content was change (that I got from the pop up), but if I change from the textbox itself it's working, the dropdownlist is changed.

Is there any suggestions that jquery detect textbox value change NOT based on user input from the textbox itself, but from the value that i got from pop-up window?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question. What version of jQuery are you using? Can you show the popup you are talking about?

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.8.21..  ooh it's a long code. My problem is not coming from the popup itself. it is working fine. the problem is when i got this value and send it to textbox in the main page, i want also rebind the dropdownlist in the main page but it is not working. I have to do keypress / change on the textbox itself, then the dropdownlist is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to trigger the change event. If you do this:

```
$('#test').live('change', function () {
    alert('test');
    $("#mydropdownlist").val(data);
});
```

Because you are setting a new value in `#mydropdownlist`. You need to make this, just next you are changing value:

```
$('#mydropdownlist').trigger('change');
```

Resume:

```
$('#test').live('change', function () {
    alert('test');
    $("#mydropdownlist").val(data);
    $('#mydropdownlist').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Hi Marcos.. I have add $('#mydropdownlist').trigger('change'); but it is still not firing.. I still have to make the change from the textbox itself so the dropdownlist is changed. What I mean is if the content of the textbox is updated/changed (from the value of popup window) so the dropdownlist is refresh the selected value based on the textbox, without i change manually from the textbox itself.

Comment: So you need to trigger the change event in the input (`#test` I believe) and not in the drop down list. `$('#test').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

> Warning a version, not work a `.live()`

Try `.on()` or `.bind()` is work fine

[image]

Its screenshot from link http://api.jquery.com/live/